# scanf get multiple values at once

Tags: c, char, scanf

I need to get in one single shot different inputs from one single line. In particular I need to get a single `char` and then, depending on which `char` value I just read, it can be a string and an `int` or a string, an `int` and another string and so on.

A sample input might be:

```
c test 20 good
d test 10
```

This is what I wrote:

```
char c, * alpha, * beta;
int val;
c = getchar();
printf("%c\n\n", c);

switch (c){
    case 'd': scanf("%s %d", alpha, &val); printf ("%c %s %d", c, alpha, val); break;
    case 'c': scanf("%s %d %s", alpha, &val, beta);  printf ("%c %s %d %s", c, alpha, val, beta); break;
    default: return 0;
}
```

Besides it needs a newline (i.e. me pressing return) to get the first char, it works fine for the `d` case but goes in segfault in the `c` case. How should I do so?

Comment: `alpha` and `beta` points to nowhere. You should allocate some memory for them.

Comment: Array of `char`s for `alpha` and `beta` or `malloc()` them.

Comment: To avoid having to enter a newline, read a string and then use sscanf. You can call it once to get the first char then a second time based on the char value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not saying that it cannot be done using `scanf()`, but IMHO, that's not the best way to do it. Instead, use `fgets()` to read the whole like, use `strtok()` to tokenize the input and then, based on the first token value, iterate over the input string as required.

A generic algorithm will look like

1. Read a whole line using [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets)
2. Tokenize using [`strtok()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) using the space ( ) as delimiter.
3. Take the first token, compare it to the desired input option `c` or `d` in your case.

   <sup>NOTE: don't confuse the character `'c'`, `'d'` and *string* `"c"`, `"d"`</sup>
4. Based on the token value, you can add more call to `strtok()` on the same string to get the values for the remaining data in the input, you can make use of the existing `switch-case` approach. Generally, continue until `strtok()` returns NULL.

That said, to answer your question,

> *it works fine for the `d` case but goes in segfault in the `c` case.*

The reason is, in the current program, your code invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), as you're using uninitialized pointers `alpha` and `beta`. You need to allocate memory to them before using, maybe through  [`malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) and family.

Answer (score 1):

```
char c, alpha[8], beta[8];
int val;
char line[32];
int state;

fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin);//input by one line
state = sscanf(line, " %c %7s %d %7s", &c, alpha, &val, beta);
if(c == 'd' && state == 3)
    printf ("%c %s %d", c, alpha, val);
else if(c == 'c' && state == 4)
    printf ("%c %s %d %s", c, alpha, val, beta);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a single `scanf`, but you need to parse the input after reading according to first character.

```
char c, alpha[20], tmp[20];
scanf("%c %s %[^\n]\n", &c, alpha, tmp);

//Here 20 is taken for example, size can be anything
```

Then you can check `c` for its value. If `c=='c'` then, you need to split `tmp` in two parts from which first is integer which you can store in `val` by `atoi()` function and the other is string.

And if `c=='d'` then, you just need to copy `tmp` into `beta` and you are done.

Comment: This invokes undefined behaviour. `alpha` and `tmp` point to nowhere.

Comment: Why `s` in `"%[^\n]s"`?

Comment: @mch It doesn't give undefined behavior if you allocate memory to it, or just make an character array. Here's the sample link :http://ideone.com/HQoiaN

Comment: @chux, it allows to take input until next `\n` (new line) character is found.

Comment: @shreyans800755  Recommend to review `scanf()` documentation.  The final `s` is not part of the `"%[^\n]"` specifier.

Comment: @chux , I'm not getting what you are trying to say. The link I commented is kind of working with `"%[&\n]"` specifier. What do you mean by 'not part of' ???

Comment: Remove the final `s` from `"%c %s %[^\n]s"` so it becomes `"%c %s %[^\n]"`.

Comment: @chux, okay, I was not aware of that till date. Thanks for that. And to flush out `\n`, I guess I have to make it like `"%c %s %[^\n]\n"`.

Comment: You certainly do _not_ want to use `"%c %s %[^\n]\n"`.  That `'\n'` at the end is not doing what you think.   More likely code should use `" %c%s %[^\n]"`.  To best " flush out `\n`", read the line with `fgets()/getline()` and then use `sscanf()`.